# How can refresh data in a table using react redux and a modal form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, modal-dialog, material-table

I'm facing an issue with refreshing data in a table using react/redux and a form. What I need to do here is to fill a modal form, than submit to my backend and then refreshing the table using setState. I can do all the things so rendering the table, showing the modal, submitting data but I can't refresh data in the table when modal is closed. How can I get this result with redux?

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ContainerHeader from 'components/ContainerHeader/index';
import IntlMessages from "../../../util/IntlMessages";
import {useDispatch, useSelector, shallowEqual} from 'react-redux';
import {
    getBanksFromBackend,
    storeBankBackend,
    updateBankBackend,
    deleteBankBackend,
} from '../../../actions';
import MaterialTable, {MTableToolbar} from "material-table";
import CardBox from "../../../components/CardBox";
import FormDialog from "./FormDialog";
import TextFields from "./TextFields";

const BanksPage = ({match}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const allBanks = useSelector(state => state.banks, shallowEqual);

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'Avatar',
                field: 'imageUrl',
                render: rowData => <img src={rowData.imageUrl} style={{width: 30, borderRadius: '50%'}}/>
            },
            {title: 'ID', field: 'id', editable: 'never'},
            {title: 'Bank Name', field: 'bnk_name'},
            {title: 'Bank Iban', field: 'bnk_iban'},
            {title: 'Bank BIC', field: 'bnk_bic'},
        ],
        data: allBanks.banks.map(bank => {
            return (
                {
                    imageUrl: 'https://img.icons8.com/office/80/000000/user.png',
                    id: bank.id,
                    bnk_name: bank.bnk_name,
                    bnk_iban: bank.bnk_iban,
                    bnk_bic: bank.bnk_bic,
                }
            )
        })
    });


    return (
        <div className="app-wrapper">
            <ContainerHeader match={match} title={<IntlMessages id="pages.banks"/>}/>
            <div className="row">

                <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12">
                    <MaterialTable
                        title="Users Table"
                        columns={state.columns}
                        data={state.data}
                        options={{
                            exportButton: true,
                            grouping: true,
                            selection: true
                        }}
                        components={{
                            Toolbar: props => (
                                <div>
                                    <MTableToolbar {...props} />
                                    <div style={{padding: '0px 10px'}}>
                                        <div className="card d-inline-block">
                                            <FormDialog {...state}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ),
                        }}
                    />
                </CardBox>

             

            </div>

        </div>
    )

}

export default BanksPage;
```

This is the modal component

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import {useDispatch, useSelector, shallowEqual} from "react-redux";
import {getBanksFromBackend, storeBankBackend} from "../../../actions";


const FormDialog = (props) => {
    console.log('Proprietà passate al form: ', props);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const initModalState = {
        open: false,
    };
    const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(initModalState);

    const [bankName, setBankName] = useState('');
    const [bankIban, setBankIban] = useState('');
    const [bankBic, setBankBic] = useState('');

    const [tableState, setTableState] = useState(props);
    console.log('Stato iniziale Tabella:', tableState);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setModalState({open: true})
    };

    const handleRequestClose = () => {
        setModalState({open: false})
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="contained" className="bg-primary text-white" onClick={() => handleClickOpen()}>Add
                Bank</Button>
            <form>
                <Dialog open={modalState.open} onClose={() => handleRequestClose()}>
                    <DialogTitle>Subscribe</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            Add Bank from Form.
                        </DialogContentText>

                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="bnk_name"
                            label="Bank Name"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={(event) => setBankName(event.target.value)}
                            defaultValue={bankName}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="bnk_iban"
                            label="Bank Iban"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={(event) => setBankBic(event.target.value)}
                            defaultValue={bankIban}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="bnk_bic"
                            label="Bank BIC"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={(event) => setBankIban(event.target.value)}
                            defaultValue={bankBic}
                        />

                    </DialogContent>

                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={() => handleRequestClose()} color="secondary">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={() => handleRequestClose()} color="primary">
                            Submit
                        </Button>

                        <Button onClick={() => new Promise((resolve) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                resolve();
                                dispatch(storeBankBackend
                                    ({
                                            bnk_name: bankName,
                                            bnk_iban: bankIban,
                                            bnk_bic: bankBic
                                        }
                                    )
                                );
                                dispatch(getBanksFromBackend());
                                handleRequestClose();
                            }, 2000)
                        })} color="primary">
                            Submit Bank
                        </Button>

                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

}

export default FormDialog;
```

Comment: can you call the promise in the onsubmit event of your form and don't frget to preventdefault the submit event.

Comment: i use a promise in the button instead of the form but basically it has the same result because I'm using useDispatch from react-redux. anyway this is the promise:
`dispatch(storeBankBackend
                                    ({
                                            bnk_name: bankName,
                                            bnk_iban: bankIban,
                                            bnk_bic: bankBic
                                        }
                                    )
                                );`

Comment: no i was saying is the promise u have written in the onclick of the Button submit bank move it to form onsubmit instead. Or try checking this button component in the browser whether it has type=submit attribute on it, if its there the the submit might be getting called

Comment: Ok I moved the promis in the form and it works like before. It works well storing the data in my backend etc..But the problem with refreshing the table with new data is still there. I need to click again on the route to refresh the table.

Comment: are u sure the dispatch is working ? just make sure reducer state is deepcloned before u change it

Comment: Yes the dispatch of saving data into backend is working well

Comment: and what about dispatch to fetch the table data again? I assumed this is the one which refreshes the data dispatch(getBanksFromBackend());

Comment: No it doesn't return anything if I assign that to a const. But why in this case is not returning anything? I use that function in redux thunk to persist the state, but if I call it here it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're cloning redux states in `BanksPage functional component`. In react components states are defined in constructor, so you're assigning them just on first render.

Later, dispatching in `FormDialog component` (maybe) works by succesfully calling the action (as [orangespark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791802/orangespark) suggested are you sure dispatch is working? You should show us your actions and reducer), but the components do not update because you're rendering a state clone memoized in `BanksPage` component.

Suggest you to try moving out columns and data objects from the state hook, it shouldn' t be necessary when working just with redux states, and go on by assigning them to variables

Comment: Yes after some tries I realized my issue was with useState hook. I never updated that state and the table was always fetching the init state. So then i put data in a const and now it works. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad to help! Kisses from Trani ;)